# Change in the identifier a capacity of the APP NOTIFICATION PUSH apple

Tags: ios

I've an existing app already deployed to  users. I've received a requirement to enable "Push notifications " option in the Identifiers. Will it impact the existing devices if I make the changes to existing Identifiers and save it?

Comment: Please be more clear about the questions you ask.. As I understand your question says you want to enable push notification capabilities for your existing app right? and if it is so you need not to concern about the existing user unless you don't want to change the bundle id of your app..

Comment: Thanks for answering, what I want to do is enable the notifications option, but I don't know if it would affect users who already have it installed

Comment: Your existing user won't get any issue..